# "The given path's format is not supported" when published on Azure

Tags: c#, json, azure, webclient, shopify

I am having a bit of an issue in downloading a JSON from Shopify using Azure web app.

The following code is working perfectly fine on my local app. However it doesn't work when I publish it on Azure, giving me "The given path's format is not supported" error.

```
public ActionResult UpdateStore()
{
    string APIUrl = "https://" + objStore.ApiKey + ":" + objStore.ApiPassword + "@" + objStore.Name + ".myshopify.com/admin/custom_collections.json";

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(objStore.ApiKey, objStore.ApiPassword);

        var htmlResult = webClient.DownloadString(APIUrl);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Shopify URL format to access store info with a private app is https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json

I've looked online quite a bit and can't find a solution to this problem. Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you verify what `APIUrl ` is in your local app vs. Azure?

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod doesn't help your cause? I use headers to pass the key and password.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter APIUrl is identical in both apps.

Comment: @HymnZ I've never used Invoke-RestMethod. After several attempts I got it right removing the part "apikey:password" from the URL.